# Angular js Array dentro de outro array

Tags: html, angularjs, api

Como faço para imprimir um array dentro de outro array, no console.log ele vem assim:

```
 Array[5]
     0:Array[10]
      0:Object
      1:Object
      2:Object
      3:Object
      4:Object
      5:Object
      6:Object
      7:Object
      8:Object
      9:Object
      10:Object
    1:Array[2]
      0:Object
      1:Object
```

to tentando com repeat normal e não vai, não sei como vou conseguir fazer...

Comment: é com angular o que você precisa?

Comment: Coloca o código do seu `ng-repeat`. Você vai ter que fazer 2 pra percorrer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente utilizar um ng-repeat dentro de outro:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
 <div ng-repeat="object in item">
   {{object.name}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Resposta prática e concisa.

Answer (score 5):

Precisa fazer um [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) dentro de outro [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), para acessar cada `array` e imprimir os valores:

***`Html`:***

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="array in arrays">
      <div ng-repeat="v in array">      
         {{v.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***`Angular`:***

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope)
    {           
       $scope.arrays = [
        [{'name':'a1'}, {'name':'a2'}],
        [{'name':'a3'}, {'name':'a4'}]
       ];
    }]);
```

<sub>O `arrays` seria o principal e `array` cada item interno.</sub>

---

***Exemplo:***

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope)
    {          
       $scope.arrays = [
        [{'name':'a1'}, {'name':'a2'}],
        [{'name':'a3'}, {'name':'a4'}]
       ];
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="array in arrays">
      <div ng-repeat="v in array">      
         {{v.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Referencias:***

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp)
- [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 5):

Faça:

**Controller**

```
$scope.meuArray = [];

//meu primeiro array é esse seu array que tem outros arrays dentro

angular.forEach(primeiroArray, function(arrays) {
    $scope.meuArray.push(arrays)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in meuArray">
     {{obj.algumAtributo}}
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como falaram acima, usar um repeat dentro de outro. Ou também pode acessar direto da seguinte forma:

```js
item[0][0] //Acessar o campo "0" do array "0"
```